# ListView dynamic customization

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I got this method setListView() which I use to populate ListView lv with data from SQLite database:

```
public void setListView (){
    String[] columns= {DbHelper.C_ID, DbHelper.col1, DbHelper.col2, DbHelper.col3, DbHelper.col4,DbHelper.col5};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, "_id DESC");


    String[] from= { DbHelper.col1, DbHelper.col2, DbHelper.col3, DbHelper.col4, DbHelper.col5}; 
    int[] to = {R.id.tvCol1, R.id.tvCol2, R.id.tvCol3, R.id.tvCol4, R.id.tvCol5};  


    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

There is a textView R.id.tvCol5 which is a part of list row (R.layout.list_row). I would like to dynamically change properties of that R.id.tvCol5 (setText, set background color etc.) based on what was entered in SQLite database column DbHelper.col5.
For example, if entry in DbHelper.col5 for that particular row is string "RED", I want to make that textView R.id.tvCol5 in that particular row to have red background and to set text to "red".

Is it possible to do that or is there some other way to accomplish that same effect?

Thank you all. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do this in your adapter, in other words you're going to have to make a custom adapter that extends a cursoradapter or baseadapter or something similar.

Then you can just simply check the value of the string and do something to the view it returns based on that value (i.e. set the background to red).